# Jenkins Ranorex plugin not executing test

Tags: jenkins, ranorex

I am new to Jenkins. I have master and slave configuration done and I have installed Jenkins on my master and want to run my ranorex test on my slave machine. All files needed for running ranorex scripts are present on my slave. When the job from the master runs, it gives error

```
[2019/11/18 17:04:51.686][Debug  ][Logger]: Console logger starting.
[2019/11/18 17:04:51.845][Failure][TestSuite]: This operation requires an interactive window station
[2019/11/18 17:04:51.858][Debug  ][Logger]: Console logger stopping.
Build step 'Execute Windows batch command' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

i tried workarounds like going to Jenkins serve and selection option of user interaction. 
If i only have bat file on slave of copying one folder to another and if i trigger job from master, it works. So master slave configuration does not have issue. Issue is running Ranorex  GUI Test on Slave.

Comment: This fixed the problem for me: https://www.ranorex.com/forum/run-testsuite-remote-server-gives-this-operation-r-t14432.html Hopefully it helps

Answer (score 0):

Jenkins needs to be running as an application not a service (which is default). Services cannot show anything with a GUI nor interact with anything with a GUI.

1. Disable the Jenkins service

   [image]
2. Run Jenkins via Command Line `java -jar jenkins.war`

   [image]

For a more detailed guide, check out the `Infrastructure` section of the Ranorex [Jenkins integration blog](https://www.ranorex.com/blog/integrating-ranorex-automation-in-jenkins-continuous-integration-process/#infrastructure).